# oCaml '\n' = '\n' wont compile

Tags: ocaml

I trying to compile a code and it gives me a non-sense error, I'm very new to oCaml so I'm missing something for sure

Here is the code

```
  let foo () =
    if '\n' = '\n' then begin
      print_endline "foo";
    end
```

Here is the error when I run `dune build`

```
File "gkoeditor.ml", line 46, characters 7-11:
46 |     if '\n' = '\n' then begin
            ^^^^
Error: This expression has type char but an expression was expected of type
         int
```

The whole source code can be found here https://github.com/dhilst/gkoeditor

I'm using Curses and Core libraries, for sure something is messing up with my environment,

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `Core` overrides the definition of `=` so that it is of type `int -> int -> bool`. The justification is that the polymorphic comparison sometimes causes problems. (It can cause an exception if the types contain functions, and can diverge in the presence of cyclic structures.)

Polymorphic `=` has never caused me any problems, and I find this redefinition to be a bit troubling for exactly the reason that it generates errors that seem to make no sense. However I can see the advantages.

At any rate, you can fix this by asking specifically for the polymorphic version of `=` in the `Poly` module.

Comment: As an alternative for to using Poly, you can: `Char.('\n' = '\n')`.